# Combining pipelines in mongodb compass gui

Tags: mongodb, pipeline

[image]

I'm reading through the mongodb pipeline documentation at https://www.mongodb.com/docs/compass/current/aggregation-pipeline-builder. Based on this in mongodb compass gui , I can create , name and save a pipeline. However to get the data I want, I would ideally like to run 2 separate queries from the original collection, then merge the results producing a 'Y' shaped pipeline. you can do something like:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "PENALTIES": {
        $ne: "$0.00"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "collection",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $and: [
              {
                "PENALTIES": {
                  $eq: "$0.00"
                }
              },
              {
                "INTEREST": {
                  $ne: "$0.00"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "new-collection"
    }
  }
])
```

but is this possible in mongo compass?

Comment: I'm not sure what your specific question is. But I think you can do away with the $unionWith altogether. Use $or in the first (and only) $match stage

Comment: it's possible in Compass console, which is at the bottom of the UI

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether I understood your question correctly, but if you're asking whether it's possible to provide a query you mentioned into compass, then yes. There are 2 ways:

1. Provide each stage separately as in the screenshot below:
   [image]
2. Provide whole aggregation query as array via `Create New` => `Pipeline From Text`:
   [image]

Comment: I kind of liked the other answer as well but thanks I learned something here.